Changing Rails gem source from Git to RubyGems
Background: I am attempting to modernise a legacy Rails app. I am not a full-time developer, nor am I the app's maintainer. All CI tests currently pass with 79% of coverage.
In the Gemfile, rails is pointed to the 3-2-stable branch of a fork of the main Rails repo. On that branch, the RAILS_VERSION file has the content 3.2.22.5.
Now, I logically assumed that removing the Git reference and pinning to 3.2.22.5 would be fine, however when I update the Gemfile and run bundle install I get a heap of dependency errors, which doesn't make sense - I'm just changing the source, not the version of the gem.
Can I force Bundler to just update the source? Should I manually hack the Gemfile.lock to reflect this?

How does the line for the rails gem in your Gemfile look like before and after the change? Does bundler attempt to use the correct/specified version after changing the source? What kind of dependencies errors are there, can you show some examples?

When pointing to a branch on GitHub, then gem picks the latest commit on that branch. Assuming that you updated your fork on a regular basis, then the latest commit on the 3-2-stable branch was e17e25c from January 2017.
But Ruby on Rails 3.2.22.5 was released in September 2016. It was probably based on the commit e4b0a5f that bumped the version number.
When you compare both commits then you will see a list of changes that were done after the latest version was released.
That said: No, the latest version from the branch is not the latest 3.2.x version that was released.
